# Python dict with list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python dict with a few key/value pairs, one value being a list, that I'm trying to convert the a Pandas dataframe. Converting the generic dict is rather straight forward with `df = pd.DataFrame(dict)`, however the list is throwing off the conversion and I'm seeking help on the best practice on how to deal with it.

For example, below in a sample dict that I'm working with:

```
{'foo': 123.0, 'ctr': 0.03, 'bar': 2.3, 'keys': ['2015-05-01', 'us', 'find foo', 'find bar', 'DESKTOP'], 'super': 5.0}
```

However below is the return of the dataframe --note that the list created multiple rows within the dataframe.

```
   super   ctr     foo    keys        bar
0     5.0  0.03    123.0  2015-05-01  2.3  
1     5.0  0.03    123.0  tha         2.3  
2     5.0  0.03    123.0  find foo    2.3  
3     5.0  0.03    123.0  find bar    2.3   
4     5.0  0.03    123.0  DESKTOP     2.3
```

Is there a better way to convert a python dict like this than simply passing it through pd.DataFrame() to have it return one row with all data within the dict?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Wait did you want the list in only 1 row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets around `dict` will do the trick

```
pd.DataFrame([dict])
```

Comment: Yeah. I'm just gonna delete my answer as I misread the question.

Comment: Any intuition on why this is the solution? Not quite sure I understand the convention here. Thanks!